# How to find consolidate top 10 employee in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i  have a larger database its imported SQL server i having many columns names 
like Employee , Transaction date, Approved date, Converted USD, . my Database Looks like

```
Employee   Approved  ConvertedUSD
  Gayu        YES         25
  susi        YES         05
  Menu        YES         25
  Susi        YES         15
  Gayu        YES         20
```

employee repeated many times table . i want final output looks like

```
 Employee   Approved  ConvertedUSD
      Gayu        YES         45
      susi        YES         20
      Menu        YES         25
```

how to consolidate  in SQL then how i will find top 10 employees from table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use aggregation and top keyword

```
select top 10 Employee,max(Approved),sum(ConvertedUSD) from table_name
group by Employee
order by sum(ConvertedUSD) desc
```

Comment: done .i have one more doubt i have a country  column in this column   so many country is there is comes many times how to consolidate with amount . can you help me

Comment: @sripriya can you please create your table with sample data https://dbfiddle.uk/  and share which country you need with output